# Android: How can you pre-populate the fragment backstack?

Tags: android, navigation, back-stack

I have an app that has one Activity that loads fragments… on initial startup it loads fragment A. From A the user can navigate to fragment B; and from B navigate to fragment C. Each time a fragment is replaced I do addToBackStack. The back button navigates as one would expect, C to B to A, and if you press back again the app exits.

I’m also using a Dropbox datastore to save all my app’s data so I can move seamlessly between devices and have all my data synced. This seems to be working well. As part of my data I store which fragment was last displayed.  Now when my app starts on a second device it correctly displays the most recently opened fragment. This works fine, however, I no longer have a backstack. For example, if the app is showing fragment C device one and then I start the app on device two, as expected fragment C is shown on device two. But when I press the back button, the app exits instead of showing fragment B. (Which makes sense since on device two the app only loaded fragment C.)

So my question: How do I pre-populate my baskstack such that when pressing the back button on device two that it navigates to fragment B?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [TaskStackBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TaskStackBuilder.html) or the activity XML declaration [android:parentActivityName](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#parent).

Answer (score 0):

I *solved* this by just committing multiple fragment transactions. Works for me

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, Fragment1(), "f1").addToBackStack(null).commit()
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, Fragment2(), "f2").addToBackStack(null).commit()
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, Fragment3(), "f3").addToBackStack(null).commit()
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, Fragment4(), "f4").commit()
```

However, for a cleaner and better solution you could also have a look at the [Jetpack Navigation UI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8GCXtCjtg40)